# How to stop Texture scrolling after certain time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this code below which, just makes a scrolling background with a Quad. My question is how can I stop the scrolling of the background after a certain time. For example, I want after I reach the end of my scrolling image, the last visible piece to be locked as the background for the rest of the level. Since my player has a constant speed I imagined that something like: after maybe 20 seconds, stop scrolling and keep the image would be possible. I am really new to Unity and I am not really sure how to do it nor I found a way that works. I would appreciate the help!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BG : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed;
    void Start()
    {

    }
    void Update()
    {
        Vector2 offset = new Vector2(0, Time.time * speed);
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTextureOffset = offset;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a simple timer with `Time.deltaTime` an `Update` function or in the a coroutine. Just increment you timer variable with `Time.deltaTime` until it reaches your target which is *30* seconds in your case.

```
float timer = 0;
bool timerReached = false;
const float TIMER_TIME = 30f;

public float speed;

void Update()
{
    if (!timerReached)
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        Vector2 offset = new Vector2(0, Time.time * speed);
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTextureOffset = offset;
    }


    if (!timerReached && timer > TIMER_TIME)
    {
        Debug.Log("Done waiting");

        //Set to false so that We don't run this again
        timerReached = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you !