# How to change something in fixed update once? (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basicly everytime second script is triggered the countdown in first script needs +10 seconds. I am able to get the value from other script correctly. But since it is fixedupdate it constantly adds 10 seconds. I need to add to countdown 10 value once and make it 0 until the second scripts is triggered again.

Comment: Make a bool, like `isTenSecondsAdded`. If this is false, add 10 seconds, make the bool true so it wont add unless it becomes false again.

Comment: `FixedUpdate` is used to perform physics stuff. You don't do your counting inside this function. Use the `Update` function. I answered similar question few days ago. You can find that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46760760/3785314)